# How to select specific words from output?

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm trying to extract specific values from cisco ios output. I'm using Ansible.

Here are my tasks:

```
  ios_command:
    commands:
      - "show run | i access-list 1 "
  register: acl

- debug:
    var=acl.stdout_lines

- debug:
    msg: "{{ acl.stdout | regex_findall('permit \\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\\b') }}"
```

and here is result I got:

```
TASK [acl : get config] *********************************
ok: [10.200.0.20]

TASK [acl : debug] **************************************
ok: [10.200.0.20] => {
    "acl.stdout_lines": [
        [
            "access-list 1 permit 10.200.0.21",
            "access-list 1 permit 10.200.0.22",
            "access-list 1 permit 10.200.0.23 0.0.255.255",
            "access-list 1 permit 10.200.0.24",
            "access-list 1 permit 10.200.0.25",
            "access-list 1 permit 10.200.0.26 0.0.0.3"
        ]
    ]
}

TASK [acl : debug] **************************************
ok: [10.200.0.20] => {
    "msg": [
        "permit 10.200.0.21",
        "permit 10.200.0.22",
        "permit 10.200.0.23",
        "permit 10.200.0.24",
        "permit 10.200.0.25",
        "permit 10.200.0.26"
    ]
}
```

All I want is to extract everything what is after 'permit', "permit + ip + mask".

```
            "permit 10.200.0.21",
            "permit 10.200.0.22",
            "permit 10.200.0.23 0.0.255.25",
            "permit 10.200.0.24",
            "permit 10.200.0.25",
            "permit 10.200.0.26 0.0.0.3"
```

What regular expression I need to use to do this things?

Comment: Why is `permit 10.200.0.21` omitted?

Comment: The leading double quote in `"permit 10.200.0.22",` is not possible when retrieving from `acl.stdout_lines` by using `regex_findall()` because it does not exist. Are you okay with not having a leading double quote?

Comment: Additionally, are the trailing quotes and commas required?

Comment: Why is `"permit 10.200.0.26 0.0.0.3` missing the trailing quote?

Comment: Sorry, I just changed IP adresess to another and that's why there're some mistakes.

Comment: Please fix your mistakes and answer my other questions. The regex will can vary wildly based on how you answer my questions.

Comment: Try `permit .*`

Comment: ```permit .* ``` only finds first permit from the list

Comment: I use other addresess so don't be mad ```"permit 10.132.0.152\\naccess-list 1 permit 10.132.0.150\\naccess-list 1 permit 10.132.0.146\\naccess-list 1 permit 10.132.0.164\\naccess-list 1 permit 10.253.1.216\\naccess-list 1 permit 10.253.1.204 0.0.0.3']"```

Comment: Your comment is illegible. Add the data to your question. Add as many variations of the data to your question as you expect to encounter. The regex can vary wildly based on the data you're dealing with

Answer (score 1):

Q: **"*Extract everything what is after 'permit', 'permit + ip + mask'*"**

A: The task below

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        out: "{{ acl.stdout_lines.0|
                 map('regex_replace', my_regex, my_replace)|
                 list }}"
      vars:
        my_regex: '^(.*) permit (.*)$'
        my_replace: 'permit \2'
```

gives

```yaml
  out:
  - permit 10.200.0.21
  - permit 10.200.0.22
  - permit 10.200.0.23 0.0.255.255
  - permit 10.200.0.24
  - permit 10.200.0.25
  - permit 10.200.0.26 0.0.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I made test play:

```
- name: Test play
  hosts: all
  vars:
    stdout_lines: [["access-list 1 permit 10.200.0.21",
 "access-list 1 permit 10.200.0.22", "access-list 1 permit 10.200.0.23 0.0.255.255", "access-list 1 permit 10.200.0.24", "access-list 1 permit 10.200.0.25", "access-list 1 permit 10.200.0.26 0.0.0.3"]]
    new_list: []
  tasks:
    - name: Fill list
      set_fact:
        new_list: "{{ new_list + item | regex_findall('permit \\b.+\\b') }}"
      with_items: '{{ stdout_lines[0] }}'

    - debug:
        msg: '{{ new_list }}'
```

And got what you want:

```
ok: [web2] => {
    "msg": [
        "permit 10.200.0.21",
        "permit 10.200.0.22",
        "permit 10.200.0.23 0.0.255.255",
        "permit 10.200.0.24",
        "permit 10.200.0.25",
        "permit 10.200.0.26 0.0.0.3"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This regex not work for me. It don't find anything. I only need working regex to make whole playbook working.

Comment: The problem may be because your acl.stdout_lines is a list of a list. I will update my example now.

Comment: BTW, why do you use stdout_lines first and use stdout later? It matters: stdout_lines – An array containing each output line of the command. Same as stdout, but stdout separates the lines using a newline (\n) characters instead of arrays. It more easy to parse each line separately than all togeter.